# Most common sublist occurance in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a list of lists,

```
{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{a,b,f},{a,b,z,}...}
```

Can I find sublists that occur very frequently in each list? For example, in this case, `{a,b}` occurs in three of the above lists, and is the most common sublist.

I can in theory check the intersection of all possible test lists with each of the above, though this is prohibitive. So is there a good way of identifying the most commonly occurring list of $k$ elements in a list of lists?

(Equivalently, if I have a hypergraph $G = (V,E)$, can I find the node subset of order $k$ with the largest hyperdegree?)

Comment: If your second sublist had been `{a, e, f}`, would you still want to `{a,b}` to qualify as the most common sublist, or would you want `{a}` to qualify?

Comment: Also, how "big" will this problem get? Are we only ever dealing with 3-element sublists? How many of these 3-element sublists can there be?

Comment: Prespecify some size $k$, e.g. $k=3$ would mean look for the most common 3-element sublist. So in the first case you give, I'm setting $k=2$ so `{a,e,f}` wouldn't count.

Comment: You mean `{a}` wouldn't count, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I mean that, will edit

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how this will scale, but you could start with something like this:

```
Sort[Counts[Catenate[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ list]]]
```

The `{2}` is because you indicated in the comments that this example was looking for 2-element subsets. You'd adjust that to look for other pre-specified subset sizes. And of course `list` is your of sets.

Comment: +1 For lengths of 10,000 and 100,000, this matches the speed of @ydd's answer.  I don't know what the OP had in mind but this seem pretty fast for even "large" lists.

Answer (score 5):

This gets big very fast but is fine for small lists. Let's use your list and $k=2$:

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {a, b, f}, {a, b, z}};
k = 2;
```

We can ask for only `Subsets` consisting of exactly `k` elements, and tally the unique subsets:

```
tab = Tally@Flatten[Subsets[#, {k}] & /@ list, 1];
tallies = tab[[All, 2]];
```

Then find the position (or positions if a tie) with the largest tally:

```
maxTalliesPos = PositionLargest@tallies
Part[tab, #, 1] & /@ maxTalliesPos
(*{{a, b}}*)
```

Comment: +1 It depends on your definition of "big".  Your code seems pretty fast for a list of length 10,000 (0.03 seconds) and even 100,000 (0.35 seconds).

Answer (score 5):

For an example we create some random list of list of say 3 elements:

```
dat = Table[Sort@RandomSample[Range[5], 3], 10]
elem = Union @@ dat

{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 5}, {2,3, 5}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}}

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Assume we are looking for sublists with "nelements" elements, for an example:

```
nelements=2
```

Possible sublists are:

```
sublists = Subsets[elem, {nelements}]

{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 
  5}, {4, 5}}
```

Now we count how many times each sublist occurs in our data:

```
counts = Count[dat, {___, #[[1]], ___, #[[2]], ___}] & /@ sublists

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4}
```

To extract the sublist that occurs most frequently is easy:

```
sublists[[ PositionLargest[counts] ]]

{{2, 3}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `GatherBy` and `Repeated`:

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {a, b, f}, {a, b, z}};

First@Flatten[GatherBy[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ list, Repeated[#] &], 2]

(*{a, b}*)
```

Considering what @JimB points out, the generalization could be seen as follows:

```
list = {{"k", "w", "z"}, {"a", "c", "s"}, {"o", "s", "s"}, {"h", "n", "u"}, 
{"a", "b", "j"}, {"f", "j", "k"}, {"a", "r", "w"}, {"f", "r", "u"},
{"b", "e", "t"}, {"a", "a", "t"}};

Sort[KeyMap[#[[1]] &, GroupBy[Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ list, 1], 
Repeated, Length]]]

(*<|{"k", "w"} -> 1, {"k", "z"} -> 1, {"w", "z"} -> 1, {"a", "c"} -> 1, 
{"a", "s"} -> 1, {"c", "s"} -> 1, {"s", "s"} -> 1, {"h", "n"} -> 1, 
{"h", "u"} -> 1, {"n", "u"} -> 1, {"a", "b"} -> 1, {"a", "j"} -> 1, 
{"b", "j"} -> 1, {"f", "j"} -> 1, {"f", "k"} -> 1, {"j", "k"} -> 1, 
{"a", "r"} -> 1, {"a", "w"} -> 1, {"r", "w"} -> 1, {"f", "r"} -> 1, 
{"f", "u"} -> 1, {"r", "u"} -> 1, {"b", "e"} -> 1, {"b", "t"} -> 1, 
{"e", "t"} -> 1, {"a", "a"} -> 1, {"o", "s"} -> 2, {"a", "t"} -> 2|>*)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for ties but the bigger problem is that it rarely gives the pair with the largest frequency.  It does give the right answer for this particular `list` but not for `list={{"k", "w", "z"}, {"a", "c", "s"}, {"o", "s", "s"}, {"h", "n", "u"}, {"a", "b", "j"}, {"f", "j", "k"}, {"a", "r", "w"}, {"f", "r", "u"}, {"b", "e", "t"}, {"a", "a", "t"}}`.

Comment: Thanks, @JimB! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the 2 element case but could be generalized.

```
list = {{a, b, c), {d, e, f}, {a, b, f},
{a, b, z}};
su = Catenate[Subsets[#,{2}]&/@list];
arg = Join[list, su];
g = RelationGraph[SubsetQ,arg];
el = Graph[DeleteCases[EdgeList[g],
DirectedEdge[a_, a_]]];
vid = VertexInDegree [el];
Pick[VertexList[el], vid,Max[vid]]
```

yields {{a,b}}

Answer (score 1):

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {a, b, f}, {a, b, z}} //
Map[Subsets[#, {2}]&] //
Catenate //
Commonest
```

> `{{a, b}}`